# Why is the newsletter subscription link hard to find?

Tags: feature-request

I think the process to subscribe for the newsletter is tedious. From what i have done you need to go to your user's page, preferences, manage newsletter subscription....
However there is an occasional popup in askubuntu.com. 
My question is why not make the popup permanent so that anyone who wishes to subscribe for the newsletter can do that with much ease?